# Objective-C: Format of NSArray vs NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm using the Quickblox API to create group chats, which requires UserID's to be sent to methods using the following format:

```
NSArray *usersIDs = @[@(55), @(678), @(22)];
```

This array outputs to the log as such:

```
Correct Format: (
        55,
        678,
        22
)
```

In my app, I'm filling the array of User ID's to an NSMutableArray, as such:

```
[holderArray addObject:[users valueForKey:@"ID"]]
```

Which outputs to the log like this (which, when I send to the method, isn't working):

```
My Array: (
        (
        55
    ),
        (
        678
    ), (
        22
    ),
)
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong with the holderArray, and how I can get the objects to add in the correct format?

**EDIT:**

Here is the log output of the users NSArray:

```
users: (
    "
  [QBUUser]:
  ID:55
  created at:2015-08-27 19:33:24 +0000
  updated at:2015-08-27 19:33:24 +0000
  externalUserID:0
  blobID:0
  facebookID:(null)
  twitterID:(null)
  full name:(null)
  email:(null)
  login:3065555555
  phone:(null)
  tags:(null)
  lastRequestAt:2015-08-29 22:49:34 +0000
  customData:(null)
  website:(null)"
)
```

Comment: Well it looks like the type of `[users valueForKey:@"ID"]` is `NSArray`.  Only you can confirm.

Comment: why are you using valueForKey? Cant you do something simple like [holderArray addObject:[users objectAtIndex:0]]; ?

Comment: @T_77 He could be using KVC or it could be a dictionary.  Either way, `objectAtIndex:` will not work.

Comment: @trojanfoe: yes, users is an NSArray. holdersArray is an NSMutableArray

Comment: @AdamG An NSArray of what?  Dictionaries?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I just added the log output of the users array to the question. thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AdamG OK, I think my answer will cover it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with passing an `NSMutableArray`, given that it's a subclass of `NSArray`, the issue is with whatever `[users valueForKey:@"ID"]` returns, as it looks like an `NSArray` itself.

From the follow-up comments it looks like it's an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects, so `users valueForKey:` will return all the IDs in the dictionaries.  If that's true then just add them to `holderArray` using `addObjectsFromArray`:

```
NSArray *idents = [users valueForKey:@"ID"];
[holderArray addObjectsFromArray:idents];
```

Comment: actually, using the code above I'm getting an error: expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type nsarray

Comment: @AdamG Yes; your original use of `valueForKey:` was correct.  Fixed.